# Add .phtml file on all pages magento 2

Tags: magento2, extensions, xml, frontend, page-layouts

I want to add my **custom.phtml** file on the top of all pages.

How can I do this using custom module ?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: in header part you want to add file?

Comment: before page-header

Comment: i have updated my answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add this code in your custom theme or module in **default.xml**:

*app/design/frontend/Namespace/Themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml*

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
           name="custom.file" 
           before="-" 
           template="Magento_Theme::html/custom.phtml"
    />
</referenceContainer>
```

you can also place it in your module:

*app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml*

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
    <block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Blockname" 
           before="-" 
           template="Vendor_Module::html/custom.phtml"
    />
</referenceContainer>
```

In this case the template must be saved under *app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/html/custom.phtml*

Comment: @D Singh, I need to achieve this under app/code. Could you please answer my question in this regard at https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/312363/magento-2-how-to-create-a-custom-block-class-and-a-custom-template-that-outputs

Comment: @CodeForGood Just add your module name like Vendor_Module instead Magento_Theme. I have provided the answer for both app/code and app/design.

Answer (score 7):

Try below steps

**Step:1** Create `default.xml`at location `app\code\<Vendor-Name>\<Module-Name>\view\frontend\layout` and add below code

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-block-name" template="<Vendor-Name>_<Module-Name>::page\custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**OR**

```
 <referenceContainer name="main.content">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-block-name" template="<Vendor-Name>_<Module-Name>::page\custom.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Step:2** Create `custom.phtml` at location `app\code\<Vendor-Name>\<Module-Name>\view\frontend\templates\page\` and add your code

for eg.

```
<?php 
     echo "Custom Block";
?>
```

**Step:3** After run compile command

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

Comment: your answer worked for me. I would like to know I can replace <referenceContainer name="page.top"> with <referenceBlock name="head.additional">. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Add Custom Template file using xml block into `app/design/frontend/<VendorName>/<ThemeName>/Magneto_Theme/layout/default.xml`

Using referenceBlock tag you can add your custom block into header block/container

```
<referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
        <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom.content" before="page-header" template="Magento_Theme::custom.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I would like to know I can replace <referenceContainer name="after.body.start"> with <referenceBlock name="head.additional">. Please let me know.

Comment: add reference container of block "head.additional" and then you can replace your referenceBlock

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use `page.wrapper` to show before header tag.

```
<referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custompage" before="-" template="{Namespace}_{Modulename}::custompage.phtml" />
 </referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I would like to know I can replace <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper"> with <referenceBlock name="head.additional">. Please let me know.