# Add popup on clicking custom button in product edit page in admin in magento 2.3

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.3, uicomponent

I have added a custom button in product edit page using `product_form.xml` like below :

**app/code/Company/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="set-to-sold" xsi:type="string">Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\SoldButton</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</form>
```

**app/code/Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Edit/Button/SoldButton.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Brainvire\ProductType\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button;

use Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Button\Generic;

class SoldButton extends Generic
{

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getButtonData()
    {
    return [
        'label' => __('Diamond is SOLD'),
        'disabled' => true,
        'on_click' => sprintf("location.href = '%s';", $this->getUrl('producttype/product/sold')),                
        'class' => 'save primary',
        'sort_order' => 5,
    ]; 

    }
}
```

the button is added like below :

[image]

This is working perfectly. A button is added, and a confirm box is also displayed on button click. But now i want to add a popup and call custom phtml in that popup on button click.

Any ideas how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add a custom phtml file in which you can create your popup and popup trigger event, and add that custom phtml file using layout file for only product add/edit page before body end.

Comment: how to add that phtml file using layout ?

Comment: Maybe you can refer this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205780/51548

Comment: I think you can not call `phtml` file in alert widget popup. there is no parameter to set template see here https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_alert.html

Comment: @ChiragPatel - I do not want to call phtml inside the alert widget popup. I want to simply open a popup on button click.

Comment: Ok, but button is present in alert popup box or in your UI-component form?

Comment: @ManashviBirla if your popup has static content you can follow chirag patel or else you can try phtml way.

Comment: Do you want to open a model popup on an action like delete, save, etc.. or want popup in the ui-form field?

Comment: It is possible to add popup in ui-form field like advance quantity in product form.

Comment: @ChiragPatel - i want to open a modal popup on custom button click. This custom button is similar to save/delete on product edit page. Check the screenshot

Comment: @ChiragPatel - any idea on the same ?

Comment: Got your point you haev to add button like `Add attribute` in product form. on click that button you wan to open popup like `Add attribute` button.

Comment: @ChiragPatel - yes exactly.