# Magento 2: Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Perfectmirrors\PmmLayout\Block\Head

Tags: magento2.3, layout, blocks, phtml, containers

I am really not sure how to create the block class `Pmm\PmmLayout\Block\Head` , function of which `$block->getAllPagesJSContent()` should be called inside my phtml file `pmm_head.phtml`

```
   <referenceBlock name="head.additional">
        <block class="Perfectmirrors\PmmLayout\Block\Head" name=""pmm_head" before="-" template="Pmm_Pmmlayout::pmm_head.phtml"/>
    </referenceBlock>
```

In the phtml file pmm_head.phtml, I should be able to do something like below to read the contents from a JS file.

```
$block->getAllPagesJSContent() to output the contents.
```

Comment: So where is the actual question ? are you asking how to achieve this on a cleaner way like described above ? Are you able to modify both JS files, or just custom-1.js ?

Comment: thanks for the comment. I edited the question a I moved further in the design. My only question now is whether one should do this under app/code or app/design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line :

```
<block class="Perfectmirrors\PmmLayout\Block\Head" name=""pmm_head" before="-" template="Pmm_Pmmlayout::pmm_head.phtml"/>
```

By

```
<block class="Perfectmirrors\PmmLayout\Block\Head" name="pmm_head" before="-" template="Perfectmirrors_Pmmlayout::pmm_head.phtml"/>
```

If the error does not resolve then please share your block file (Perfectmirrors\PmmLayout\Block\Head)

Thanks